Relating the "resolution" of a finite Fourier series representation to the shortest wavelength in the series
Suppose I choose to represent functions defined on $[0,1]$ via Fourier-series approximations of the form
$f(x) \approx \hat{f}(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_i k_i\cos(n\pi x)$
or similar for some finite $n$, where $k_i$ is a normalisation constant equal to 1 for $i=0$ and $\sqrt{2}$ for $i > 0$.
The individual terms in this series are cosine waves with wavelength equal to $2/n$, and the shortest wavelength is $2/N$.
I want to be able to approximate $f$ accurately, in the sense that
$\frac{\int\limits_0^1 (f(x)-\hat{f}(x))^2dx}{\int\limits_0^1 f(x)^2dx} < \epsilon$
for some appropriately small $\epsilon$.
My non-rigorous understanding is that an approximation of this form can accurately represent functions whose "features" are significantly larger than the minimum wavelength $2/N$ (e.g. where $f$ is piecewise linear, with each linear portion having size >> $2/N$) and that it cannot accurately represent functions with significant features at scales much less than $2/N$. (An obvious example of the latter being $f(x) = \cos((N+1)\pi x)$.)
Is there a citeable result along these lines?

Maybe something like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate
